# Getting multiple inputs in one line until user press enter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

**What I am trying to do is that:**

> 2 *(number of test cases)*
>
> 4 7 8 15 16 *(test case 1)*
>
> *here will be output, for example will print the max number*
>
> 7 97 1 2 9 *(test case 2)*
>
> *here is output again*

I will have some statements in each test case until user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> button. I saw some similar questions but none of solutions which I tried didn't work.

This is what I tried lastly:

```
Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
int test = Integer.parseInt(cin.nextLine());

for (int k = 0; k < test; k++) {
    while (cin.next() != "\\n") {
        int number = cin.nextInt();
        //do something
    }
    //print output
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read whole input line and then create a new `Scanner` for reading integers from this line:

```
Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
int test = Integer.parseInt(cin.nextLine());

for (int k = 0; k < test; k++) {
    String line  = cin.nextLine();
    Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
    while (lineScan.hasNextInt()) {
        // print number
        System.out.println(lineScan.nextInt());
    }
    //print output
}
```